# How to configure Selenium HTML Reports in Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, mojo

We have a Java MOJO configured in Jenkins. Once the code is build in CI, surefire reports would be generated. We have Junit and Selenium test cases to test the application.

I need to present the results coming from the test cases in a HTML format. Is there any plugin available for Jenkins to display the content in HTML format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install the [Selenium HTML Report Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/seleniumhtmlreport+Plugin). If you are not aware of installing the plugin, use this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins)

After installing the Selenium HTML report plugin, Add the post build script to generate the HTML content from the surefire reports. Use the following screenshot for configuring the HTML plugin..

[image: Configuring the SeleniumHTML Report plugin in Jenkins]

Change the **ProjectRoot** with your MOJO

Comment: For those stumbling on this 6+ years after it was posted - this plugin no longer works and doesn't appear to supported any more.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install "Selenium HTML Report Plugin" into jenkins.
2. In the post build action add below actions.

   **action 1: Publish Selenium HTML Report**

   **value**: */(Job Name)/workspace/      --> note: (place your test resultFile in this folder)

   **action 2: Publish Selenium Report**

   **value**:  **/(Job Name)/workspace/*.html

This way we can generate a successful selenium report.