# How to Configure Selenium Report plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have gone through this link but it hasn't helped. [How to configure Selenium HTML Reports in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082425/how-to-configure-selenium-html-reports-in-jenkins)

This is the Error which i am getting :

```
12:11:26.345 INFO - Killing Firefox...
Tests failed, see result file for details: /home/jenkins/Testsresults/results.html
12:11:26.424 INFO - Shutting down...
Xvfb stopping
Publishing Selenium report...
Missing directory */home/jenkins/Testresults/
Build step 'Publish Selenium Html Report' marked build as failure
Publishing Selenium report...
ERROR: No Test Report Found
Build step 'Publish Selenium Report' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Hello @kwoks, I Have the same issue and havent found a solution so far. Have you find something ? Have a clue ?

Comment: Check the answer below !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check if the /home/jenkins/Testresults/ folder exists on your Jenkins machine, if not, manually create it and try again.

EDIT: looks like a stray '*'

Comment: Testresult folder exists !

Comment: I removed * in the folder path and result file path and it worked :)

Comment: Excellent :) I almost explicitly mentioned the * !